# Solve: determine as the parameters $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ the rank of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

### **Determine as the parameters $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ the rank of the following matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} a+b & a &b \\ b & a & 0 \\ a & b & b\end{pmatrix} $$**

How can I solve this? by trying to calculate the determinant, I got: $b^3 -b^2+a^2b+ab^2-2ab$, I think I need to calculate the roots of $a$ and $b$ in order to calculate the rank of the matrix, going to replace the roots from time to time to the matrix, but I not so sure this is the right way.

Can someone give me some tips to solve this exercise, or give me the solution step-by-step? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{vmatrix} a+b & a& b \\ b & a & 0\\a & b & b\end{vmatrix}=b\begin{vmatrix} a+b & a& 1 \\ b & a & 0\\a & b & 1\end{vmatrix}=b\begin{vmatrix} a+b & a& 1 \\ b & a & 0\\-b & b-a & 0\end{vmatrix}=b^2 \begin{vmatrix} 1 & a \\ -1 &b-a\end{vmatrix}=b^3$$

Hence if $b\ne 0$, the rank is $3$.

If $b=0$, consider two cases, $a=0$ and $a \ne 0$. I will leave this to you as an exercise.

Comment: I found that if $a=0$ the rank$=1$ and if $a\ne0$ the rank$=2$, it's correct?

Comment: check your answer for $a=0$ again. correct answer for $a \ne 0$.

Comment: with $a=0$ and $b=0$ I get a zero matrix so the rank is just zero, right?

Comment: good job, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help !